Are serial types like smallserial, serial, bigserial not available in TypeORM?
While creating an entity I wanted to use serial as my Column type, but typescript gives me error:
Type '"smallserial"' is not assignable to type
I checked other serial types and got same error. Are these types not available? I am using Postgres database.
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'smallserial'})
id: number


Why do you need it? For id's you can/could/should use an IDENTITY column, using an INT, SMALLINT or whatever you need.

That is because *serial is not actually a type, it is a macro that does multiple things as explained in the link.  You probably want to use the underlying type, smallint, integer and bigint for smallserial, serial and bigserial respectively.

From 8.1.4 Serial Types.

The data types smallserial, serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases).

The corresponding types are smallint, int, and bigint.
For example, one uses an integer to reference a serial primary key. some_id integer not null references some_table(id).
